# Reputation change due to "user removed"?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I recently noticed that I went down a bit in reputation and there is a 35p minus with the explanation "user removed", which didn't make sense.

Not that the reputation is matters but it would be good to understand what happened. Anyone can enlighten me on that point?

**EDIT:**
isn't it odd, that the reputation a person has depends on the other peoples' existence? I mean consider this excerpt from SO-FAQ regarding reputation:

> "Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts
>   you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re
>   talking about."

The fact that a particular answer I have provided is disintegrated due a user being removed, doesn't mean I know any less or have contributed any less than what I did before?

I realize this is very trivial, since it doesn't really matter, and it effects everyone just as much, but it's still an interesting meta-problem to think about.

Comment: I don't disagree. I claim status-by-design on this, but at the same time, it's not every day that users are removed causing such a ripple effect.

Comment: From a “philosophical” standpoint, I would say upvotes/downvotes from a removed user _should_ be removed, while upvotes/downvotes from other people, even if placed on later removed questions/answers should stay. I guess. But see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The fact that a particular answer I have provided is disintegrated due a user being removed, doesn't mean I know any less or have contributed any less than what I did before?

The answer you provided is still there. But the deleted user's vote on it is not. When the user is removed, whatever votes they cast are removed as well.

There's [some debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) over whether this entirely makes sense, but for the moment it is by design.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closer, it says "user was removed."

Most likely, an answer you provided (with, I speculate, two upvotes and an accepted answer) was to a question asked by a user who no longer exists (user and his content had been removed) in Sports SE.

Comment: thanks for the reply, please see my edit (it was too long as a comment)